# PHP Set Variable if Empty?

Tags: php, variables, text, get, store

I have this variable, let's say

`$text`

I also have a website, site.com/

I want to get this:

```
site.com/index.php?text=hello
```

And get the page to display "hello", and setting the variable `$hello` to store 'hello' if no other text is entered. 
Right now, I feel embarrased to ask this. This is really basic, and I have gotten it to work many times, but this time I don't know where I went wrong.

My code is:

```
$text = $_GET['text'];
    if ($text = ''){
    $text = 'hello';
    }
echo $text;
```

What's wrong with this?

Comment: You can always use [empty()](http://php.net/empty).

Comment: You can use [`empty()`](http://php.net/empty): `echo (!empty($_GET['text'])) ? $_GET['text'] : '';`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=` means **assignment**, while `==` means **comparison**.

Another way to test if the `$text` is empty:

```
$text = $_GET['text'];
    if (empty($text)){
       $text = 'hello';
    }
echo $text;
```

or directly

```
if(!isset($_GET['text'])) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($text = ''){
```

This is an <strike>affectation</strike>**assignment**, not a test.

```
if ($text == ''){ // should work :-)
```

Answer (score 2):

You did a tiny little mistake ;-)

If you want to *compare* things you need to use two equality signs. Otherwise it is a assignment.

```
if($text == '') {
    $text = 'name';
}
```

The assignment is always true since there is no problem writing a string to $text

Answer (score 2):

Use == operator for comparision...